# Shortcut for Preview sketch tool

Tags: preview

Nearly every time I open Preview.app I will then immediately press the toolbox button and then the sketch button.

[image]

Is there a shortcut to access the sketch tool or some way to put the sketch button on my default toolbar?

Comment: Use CMD-I (that's I as in eye) to always show markup toolbar, removing one step.

Answer (score 3):

This workaround applies to **Preview.app 9.0 (909.12)** in **macOS Sierra 10.12.2** and will most likely break in future releases.

1. Launch AppleScript Editor and enter the following.

   ```
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview"
       activate
       set markup to checkbox 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1
       tell markup
           if not (its value as boolean) then
               click markup
               delay 0.1
           end if
       end tell
       set sketch to checkbox 1 of toolbar 2 of window 1
       tell sketch
           if not (its value as boolean) then
               click sketch
           end if
       end tell
   end tell
   ```
2. Launch Preview, open a document, switch back to AppleScript Editor, and run your script. You will most likely get at least one error about AppleScript Editor requiring permission to use accessibility features.
3. Open **System Preferences**. Open the **Security & Privacy** pane. Click the **Privacy** tab. Click **Accessibility**. Click **"Click the lock to make changes."** Enter your password and click **Unlock**. Click the plus sign. Select **Automator** and click **Open**. Repeat, adding **Script Editor**. Make sure the checkboxes next to **Automator** and **Script Editor** are checked in the list.

(Hopefully, you'll only have to do step 3 once... until the next macOS upgrade.)

4. Go back to Script Editor, and try running your script again. Hopefully, in Preview, the Sketch tool will now be selected.
5. In Script Editor, save your script as **an application** somewhere in your home folder.
6. Find the application you just saved using Finder or Spotlight. Run the application. You will get another error about accessibility access.
7. Return to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**.
8. Click the little plus sign again. Browse to the application you just saved, and add it to the list. Make sure the check box next to it is checked.
9. Now, run your application from the Finder or Spotlight again. Hopefully you will not get an error this time.
10. Open **Automator**. Choose **File** > **New**. Choose **Service**. Under "Service receives selected," choose **no input**. Click **any application** and choose **Other...** Choose **Preview**.
11. In the "Actions" search box, type **application**. Drag **Launch Application** over to the "Drag actions or files here to build your workflow" panel.
12. Under **Launch Application**, choose **Other...**, then browse to your application.
13. Save the automator action (Service) with a sensible name, like "Preview Sketch Mode" or something easy to remember that you can type **exactly**.
14. Make sure the automator action works.
15. Launch **System Preferences** and go to **Keyboard**. Click **Shortcuts**. Click **App Shortcuts**. Click the plus sign. Under **Application**, choose **Preview**. Under **Menu Title**, type the **exact** name of the service name you saved in step 13 above. Assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

You should now have a keyboard shortcut that enables Sketch mode in Preview.